# what do dots, dashes, caps on wires indicate?

Tags: wire, code

I found these 5 wires with markings on them attached to an electronic device's control panel. Does each marking signify a function? If so what are they?

[image]

Comment: Yes, each marking signifies a function determined by the designer and known only to the designer and others to which documentation has been furnished.

Answer (score 7):

I think these patterns are printed out so that one can differentiate the individual wires at the two ends of the cable.  It's probably cheaper than using multiple colors.  If you look carefully, you'll see that many lamp cords have different texturing on one of the wires for that reason.

Comment: I wish they did this instead of colours. How am I suppose to tell the difference between pastel shades of colours?

Comment: It's not just shades of pastel.  Using symbols rather than colors also helps to accommodate people who may be totally or partially color blind.

Comment: @SteveSh, it also helps accommodate situations where the lighting is some color other than white.